# 'How much is the world so hard to live in, that some people give up their lives?' Is this sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, interrogatives

I want to express

> 'The world is so hard to live in, that some people give up their lives.'

as an interrogative form, so that I can emphasize the meaning of it. Please let me know if this sentence is too redundant and awkward or if there is a better and clear expression:

> How much is the world so hard to live in, that some people give up their lives?

Comment: Can you give some context about why you are re-phrasing this? I attempted  a couple of answers but deleted them because it didn't seem right. Are you asking "Why" is the world like this? "How" (in what circumstances) could the world come to this? *What are you asking?*

Comment: 'How much hard'...maybe? I thought 'how' can only means 'in what way or manner'. So I used 'how much' to mean 'in certain degree or level.' https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/how

Comment: By "interrogative form" do mean "A sentence that asks whether this is true", or do you mean "A sentence that asks to what extent this is true"?

Comment: "A sentence that asks to what extent this is true". And I wanted to emphasize it, not to be answered. like 'It's a tough day, isn't it?'

Comment: Or I should just study English more. It was such a complicated idea for me to deliver, in my English level.

Answer (score 1):

"Is the world so hard to live in that some people give up their lives?"

Or based on your edit "How hard is the world [to live in] that some people give up their lives?" but that would normally be more of a rhetorical question.

Or even more abstractly "How could it be [the case that] the world is so difficult to live in that..." etc.

Comment: Most readers would understand "hard" as "hard to live in" in that context.

Comment: But if you are asking "how much?" you could say something like "How difficult is the world [or: "could the world be?"] that... etc.

Comment: Maybe that's the expression I was looking for. I've realized 'much' was redundant.

Comment: Are you asking "to what extent"? (on a scale of e.g. not much..a bit.. a lot etc) -- if you aren't asking about a "quantity" then you are right that "how much" is redundant.

Comment: @seventyeightist --Wouldn't "give up **on** their lives" be better?